# Is this scene a homage to The Jerk?

Tags: unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt, the-jerk

In *Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt*, Season 2 Episode 1, Fred Armisen sings a song whilst playing a ukulele:

[image]

It seems to me that this bears an uncanny resemblance to the scene from *The Jerk* where Steve Martin plays a ukulele also and sings a song to his girlfriend:

Given the scene's setup and wig, is there any evidence that this is a homage to the same scene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character is [inspired by Robert Durst](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/04/16/kimmy-schmidt-robert-durst-fred-armisen):

> It takes barely any time at all for Netflix’s *Unbreakable Kimmy
>   Schmidt* to offer up one of the best gags of its second season: A
>   recurring appearance from infamous true crime subject, **Robert Durst**.
>
> Only, it’s not Durst, but SNL alum **Fred Armisen’s spot-on impression
>   of the Durst presented to the world in HBO’s 2015 series, *The Jinx*.**
>   The docu-series about the self-admittedly homicidal billionaire
>   eccentric quickly captivated the country last February and March, with
>   Durst mania reaching its height at the tail end of the spring, just as
>   the writers of Kimmy began to discuss season two.
>
> “In and out of that summer, obviously, everyone was just obsessed with
>   The Jinx when we sat down to write,” co-creator Robert Carlock says
>   between chuckles, as if he knows full well just how absurd Armisen’s
>   cameo truly is. [...]
>
> Durst initially pops up as a former flame of nutjob landlady Lillian
>   (Carol Kane), but his role takes on a bigger shape in the season when
>   the two rekindle their romance over roller skates and ukulele duets.
>
> The biggest champion of introducing Durst as a love interest for Kane
>   was Carlock’s co-creator, Tina Fey. “Tina really insisted that the
>   overlap between these two New York eccentrics, as one might term them,
>   was just too good,” says Carlock. “And I think Lillian has a very high
>   level of tolerance for violent eccentricities.”

I suspect the use of the ukulele is merely a device to display the character's eccentricity.

It should be noted that [Vulture also noticed the similarity](http://www.vulture.com/2016/04/unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt-recap-season-2-episode-1.html):

> Not many shows would make the call to wrap up a season premiere with a
>   *Jerk*-meets-*Jinx* ukulele duet in a roller rink, but in Kimmy Schmidt's
>   weird world, that's par for the course. Pretty damn hilarious, too.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've never seen the jinx but did hear about it. I live in UK so the cultural reference was lost on me but it immediately reminded me of that scene from the jerk